# Hadoop 2.6.4 and Big File

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs

I am a new user of Apache Hadoop. There is one moment which I do not understand. I have a simple cluster (3 nodes). Every node have about 30GB free space. When I look at Overview site of Hadoop I see DFS Remaining:  90.96 GB. I set the Replication factor to 1.

Then I create one file 50GB and try to upload it to HDFS. But space is out. Why? Do I can't upload file which more than free space one node of cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Hadoop : Definitive Guide

> Hadoop’s default strategy is to place the first replica on the same node as the client (for clients running outside the cluster, a node is chosen at random, although the system tries not to pick nodes that are too full or too busy). The second replica is placed on a different rack from the first (off-rack), chosen at random. The third replica is placed on the same rack as the second, but on a different node chosen at random. Further replicas are placed on random nodes on the cluster, although the system tries to avoid placing too many replicas on the same rack.
>   This logic makes sense as it decreases the network chatter between the different nodes.

I think it depends on, whether the client is same as a Hadoop node or not. If the client is a Hadoop node then all the splits will be on the same node. This doesn't provide any better read/write throughput in-spite of having multiple nodes in the cluster. If the client is not same as the Hadoop node, then the node is chosen at random for each split, so the splits are spread across the nodes in a cluster. Now, this provides a better read/write throughput.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I didn't understand anyway how to upload a big file. I was setup HDFS gateway for NFS. I was mounted NFS folder from my windows computer. And I trying upload big file. But as I see only one node have decreasing space. What I do wrong?